# ElasticBeanstalk eb deploy command uploading virtual-env folder while being present on .ebignore Linux 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to upgrade my Beanstalk platform from Linux to Linux 2.

With following config:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: app_name.settings.dev
    PYTHONPATH: $PYTHONPATH
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: app_name.wsgi:application
    NumProcesses: 3
    NumThreads: 20
  aws:autoscaling:asg:
    Cooldown: '720'
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    "/static/": app_name/static/
```

I also have my virtual-env folder under both gitignore and ebignore. Both are present in the project root directory.

However, deployment is failing with errors on the following command failing:

```
Stop running the command. Error: chown /var/app/staging/custom-env/lib64: no such file or directory
```

I don't get why is even the `custom-env` folder being upload. As per my understanding: It shouldn't be uploaded as this folder is present in the `.ebignore` file

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I'm having a very similar problem.